# jQuery or css fade the text In&Out depending on the scroll in the PARENT div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parallax

I have 3 blocks which are 100% height EACH...

this is the code

```
<div class="block12"><span>VRTUALL</span></div>
<div class="block12"><span>VR FOR ALL</span></div>
<div class="block12"><span>Virtual Reality for All</span></div>
```

It's working fine but without any effects, I'm trying to make (when scrolling) the Span fade out when for example first one is almost out of viewport and fade out the next one when it appeared in the viewport etc.. here is an example (http://www.magicleap.com/#/home) just scroll down in this website and you'll see how the text fades In and Out...

Here is my website where I'm trying to achieve this (http://www.vrtuall.com)

Please can somebody help me with this, I'm not very good into all this, I tried ALL possible codes I found here and on the net but none worked..

Comment: Please post your *relevant* code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.